# Execute remote exchange powershell command with C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I can execute a powershell command on a remote machine, and I can execute powershell exchange snapin commands, but I can't figure out how to do both. The issue resides in the `RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()` method.

A WSManConnectionInfo object lets me target a remote host like so:

```
WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(
    new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExchangeServerURI"]),
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange",
    new PSCredential(Username, secureString));
```

And a RunspaceConfugation + PSSnapInInfo lets me target a snapin like so:

```
RunspaceConfiguration rsConfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
PSSnapInException snapInException = null;
PSSnapInInfo info = rsConfig.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin", out snapInException);
```

But I can only feed one or the other to CreateRunspace(). The Runtime object it returns has properties for ConnectionInfo and RunspaceConfiguration, but they're both readonly. Is this an intentional design that you can't remotely execute code with powershell snapins, or is there a way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is define a remoting endpoint (on the remote machine) that configures itself to have the desired pssnapin loaded e.g.:

```
Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Name ExAdminShell -StartupScript InitScript.ps1
```

Then you would connect to that endpoint.

Another thought, does it not work if you just add the Add-PSSnapin to the top of the script you're going to run on the remote machine?   Keep in mind that snapins are bit-specific so if you are connecting to a 32-bit endpoint the snapin better be 32-bit and registered.  Ditto for a 64-bit snapin.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem recently that the RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace() constructor only allows either ConnectionInfo or RunspaceConfiguration parameters and not both.  I considered  optional arguments but later noticed that these properties where readonly.

I don't know if it's possible for sure yet, still testing myself, but possible making the remote connection first and then calling the PSSnapIn under the PowerShell runspace might work...

```
    public static Collection<PSObject> remoteExchangePowerShell(string domain, string username, SecureString password, string remoteFQDNServer)
    {
        PSCredential remoteCredential = new PSCredential(string.Format("{0}\\{1}", domain, username), password);

        WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}/Powershell?serializationLevel=Full", remoteFQDNServer)), 
            "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", remoteCredential);

        /*Just for PowerShell
         WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}/Powershell?serializationLevel=Full", remoteFQDNServer) + ":5985/wsman"),
             "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell", remoteCredential);*/

        connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;

        using (Runspace remoteRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
        {
            //remoteRunspace.Open();

            using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                PSSnapInException psException;

                powershell.Runspace.RunspaceConfiguration.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010", out psException);

                ....

            }
        }
    }
```

I would be interested to hear back on your results.